# "It's so X as Y" Vs. "It's as X as Y"

Tags: comparative-constructions

I learnt that the structure of comparative sentence is between two "as". For example:

> It is **as** big **as** an elephant.
>
> He is **as** clever **as** Einstein.
>
> She is **as** nice **as** her brother.

Now my question is if the following structure is equal **in correctness and meaning**?

> It is **so** big **as** elephant.
>
> He is **so** clever **as** Einstein.
>
> She is **so** nice **as** her brother.

As you can see, I just changed the first "as" with "so". Is that fine?

Comment: Remember that when you use a countable noun, like *elephant*, you have to use an article or other determiner with it, like "...as **an** elephant."

Comment: Yes, you're right. I omited it by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

While *'as....as'* is used to compare, *'so...as'* is mainly for *negative* sentences. So, the latter examples in your questions don't seem to be usual.

> She's as nice as her brother

But...

> She's ***not*** so nice as her brother.

Comment: I am sorry but based on Google-Ngram it doesn't seems like your answer: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=so+nice+as%2Cnot+so+nice+as&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cso%20nice%20as%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnot%20so%20nice%20as%3B%2Cc0 In addition a lot of examples show both examples. If you say that it's not fine, then please show reference for that.

Comment: Looks good to me, see Ngram https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=not+so+good+as%2Cnot+so+bad+as%2Cnot+so+well+as%2C+not+so+nice+as&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnot%20so%20good%20as%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnot%20so%20bad%20as%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnot%20so%20well%20as%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnot%20so%20nice%20as%3B%2Cc0

Comment: [*"His betters he envies, because he is not so good as they"*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=XLQrAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA56&dq=%22not+so+good+as%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjn-eK5_-3aAhVPVsAKHY_jDwMQ6AEIPTAE#v=onepage&q=%22not%20so%20good%20as%22&f=false) If the author had said "*not* ***as*** *good as they*" the meaning would be different.